# Migrating Symfony Project from Windows to Server in Linux

Tags: symfony, web-deployment, development-environment, production-environment, dev-to-production

Once my web application is running on local, I want to pour it into a server. Whenever I upload it, I'm having problems with the routing staff.

I guess it is searching on local routes (in full paths) instead of server ones.

So this is the error given:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\src\MyBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Obviously, it is mixing Windows routing(computer) with Linux paths (server).
I have been looking for the config files or whatever, searching in the routing files but nothing changed.

*Edit: I am currently using 2,8 version of Symfony

Comment: Have you execute `cache:clear` console command after moving your project?

Comment: Definetly that was the problem...so embarrasing

Comment: You shouldn’t be embarrassed. It happens periodically to every one of us. When it’s not the Symfony cache anymore, it’s the OpCache, or Memcache, or the reverse proxy.

Comment: Read [How to Deploy a Symfony Application](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)

Comment: I have added this case to the troubleshooting checklist for this problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021 . Please feel free to suggest edits for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should make sure you’re not uploading the `app/cache` directory, or that you’re clearing the cache after uploading.